# SwiftUI - Align contents of Button to the left

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a design that looks like this:

[image]

When I wrap it in a Button, the Image and "HOME" text move toward the center:

[image]

I am trying to keep the contents aligned to the left but I'm having trouble. Here's the code that makes up this component.

```
struct HomeSection: View {
var body: some View {
    Button(action: {

    }) {
        Group {
            Spacer().frame(width: 0, height: 36.0, alignment: .topLeading)
            HStack {
                Image("home")
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 24, height: 24)
                    .foregroundColor(.navigationTextGrey)

                Text("HOME")
                    .bold()
                    .font(.system(size: 17.0))
                    .foregroundColor(Color.navigationTextGrey)
                    .padding(.leading, 4.0)
            }
            Rectangle()
                .fill(Color.navigationTextGrey)
                .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 60, height: 1)
                .padding(.top, 6.0)
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can add a `Spacer` to the `HStack` and padding to align the house image with the rectangle.

```swift
var body: some View {
    Button(action: {
    }) {
        Group {
            Spacer().frame(width: 0, height: 36.0, alignment: .topLeading)
            HStack {
                Image("home")
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 24, height: 24)
                    .foregroundColor(.navigationTextGrey)
                    .padding(.leading, 30.0)
                Text("HOME")
                    .bold()
                    .font(.system(size: 17.0))
                    .foregroundColor(Color.navigationTextGrey)
                    .padding(.leading, 4.0)
                Spacer()
            }
            Rectangle()
                .fill(Color.navigationTextGrey)
                .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 60, height: 1)
                .padding(.top, 6.0)
        }
    }
}
```

This is the end result: [image]

Also, you can use a [`Divider()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/divider) which does the same thing as your rectangle if you want to clean up your code a little:

```swift
Divider()
    .padding([.leading, .trailing], 30)
```

Answer (score 5):

Yeah this can be cleaned up a lot.

```
var body: some View {
    Button(action: {
    }) {
        VStack(spacing: 6) {
            HStack(spacing: 4) {
                Image("home")
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 24, height: 24)
                Text("HOME")
                    .bold()
                    .font(.system(size: 17.0))
                Spacer()
            }
            Divider()
        }
    }
    .foregroundColor(.navigationTextGrey)
    .padding([.leading, .trailing], 30)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should try adding a Spacer and alignment for the HStack

```
        HStack() {
            Image("home")
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 24, height: 24)
                .foregroundColor(.navigationTextGrey)

            Text("HOME")
                .bold()
                .font(.system(size: 17.0))
                .foregroundColor(Color.navigationTextGrey)
                .padding(.leading, 4.0)

            Spacer()
            }
```

Comment: There is no leading alignment for HStack

Answer (score 1):

Try using a spacer with maxWidth = .infinity

```
Spacer().frame(maxWidth:.infinity)
```